# delete specific rows from table

Tags: eclipse, egl

I m working on an example of this tutorial:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMQ79_9.1.1/com.ibm.egl.richui.sql.tutorial.doc/topics/egl_richui_sql_intro.html

I want to change it a little bit.I added another dojo button and when I click on it I want to delete the consecutive rows who have amount 0 and the same category. So far, my code deletes only one element the first one.

Here is my code and the example data to help you.

[image]

```
 for(i int from 1 to allPayments.getSize())
        if(allPayments[i].amount == 0)
            allPayments.removeElement(i);
            if((i+1)<=allPayments.getSize())

                if((allPayments[i+1].amount == 0)&&(allPayments[i].category==allPayments[i+1].category))
                    allPayments.removeElement(i+1);
                 end
            end
            //exit for;
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask you if the 1st element in the array starts at 0 ?
If that is the case, looks like your incrementing the array so array[0] does not fall under your conditions.

Comment: the declaration of array is  allPayments paymentRec[0];
I didn't change anything from the example.